# Symfony2: Spaces in image when using GD

Tags: php, symfony, gd

I'm currently working on a project where I have to render barcodes to print them. To do so, I use a code I got online which works fine if I use it in a separate file. The only problem is I have to use it with symfony 2.1.

This script uses GD to draw a barcode. The problem is that when I try to display the image with the imagepng function, I have an error. After trying to download the png as an attachement file, I noticed that there is 4 spaces before the binary data in the png file. It starts like that :

```
    ‰PNG
```

If I remove the spaces manually, the image is displayed but I need to display the png directly in the browser.

Do you have an idea as to why the spaces are prepended to the image file?

Here is the code used to generate the png.

```
 public function barcodeAction($text) {
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', sprintf('attachment; filename="%s.png"', $text));
    $size = "40";
    $code_string = "";

    $chksum = 104;

    $code_array = array(" " => "212222", "!" => "222122", "\"" => "222221", "#" => "121223", "$" => "121322", "%" => "131222", "&" => "122213", "'" => "122312", "(" => "132212", ")" => "221213", "*" => "221312", "+" => "231212", "," => "112232", "-" => "122132", "." => "122231", "/" => "113222", "0" => "123122", "1" => "123221", "2" => "223211", "3" => "221132", "4" => "221231", "5" => "213212", "6" => "223112", "7" => "312131", "8" => "311222", "9" => "321122", ":" => "321221", ";" => "312212", "<" => "322112", "=" => "322211", ">" => "212123", "?" => "212321", "@" => "232121", "A" => "111323", "B" => "131123", "C" => "131321", "D" => "112313", "E" => "132113", "F" => "132311", "G" => "211313", "H" => "231113", "I" => "231311", "J" => "112133", "K" => "112331", "L" => "132131", "M" => "113123", "N" => "113321", "O" => "133121", "P" => "313121", "Q" => "211331", "R" => "231131", "S" => "213113", "T" => "213311", "U" => "213131", "V" => "311123", "W" => "311321", "X" => "331121", "Y" => "312113", "Z" => "312311", "[" => "332111", "\\" => "314111", "]" => "221411", "^" => "431111", "_" => "111224", "\`" => "111422", "a" => "121124", "b" => "121421", "c" => "141122", "d" => "141221", "e" => "112214", "f" => "112412", "g" => "122114", "h" => "122411", "i" => "142112", "j" => "142211", "k" => "241211", "l" => "221114", "m" => "413111", "n" => "241112", "o" => "134111", "p" => "111242", "q" => "121142", "r" => "121241", "s" => "114212", "t" => "124112", "u" => "124211", "v" => "411212", "w" => "421112", "x" => "421211", "y" => "212141", "z" => "214121", "{" => "412121", "|" => "111143", "}" => "111341", "~" => "131141", "DEL" => "114113", "FNC 3" => "114311", "FNC 2" => "411113", "SHIFT" => "411311", "CODE C" => "113141", "FNC 4" => "114131", "CODE A" => "311141", "FNC 1" => "411131", "Start A" => "211412", "Start B" => "211214", "Start C" => "211232", "Stop" => "2331112");
    $code_keys = array_keys($code_array);
    $code_values = array_flip($code_keys);
    for ($X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X++) {
        $activeKey = substr($text, ($X - 1), 1);
        $code_string .= $code_array[$activeKey];
        $chksum = ($chksum + ($code_values[$activeKey] * $X));
    }
    $code_string .= $code_array[$code_keys[($chksum - (intval($chksum / 103) * 103))]];

    $code_string = "211214" . $code_string . "2331112";

    // Pad the edges of the barcode
    $code_length = 10;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= strlen($code_string); $i++) {
        $code_length = $code_length + (integer) (substr($code_string, ($i - 1), 1));
    }
    $img_width = $code_length;
    $img_height = $size;

    $image = imagecreate($img_width + 10, $img_height);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

    imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);

    $location = 10;
    for ($position = 1; $position <= strlen($code_string); $position++) {
        $cur_size = $location + (substr($code_string, ($position - 1), 1) );
        imagefilledrectangle($image, $location, 0, $cur_size, $img_height, ($position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black));
        $location = $cur_size;
    }
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
    return $response;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:**
The problem is solved.
For that, I'd like to thank both Diego Agulló and hacfi.
Of course, I checked before posting if there were any leading whitespaces in the php file containing the function so I couldn't figure out the origin of the problem. The last message of hacfi made me realise that the spaces could come from a file that was send before the current file. 
I discovered the linebreaks in the files I use to authenticate my users (the authentification provider and listener).

So, again, thank you.

Comment: Most likely you've left some spaces before `<?php` or after `?>`, so the headers are sent prior to rendering/outputting the PNG.

Comment: Well, the thing is there is no space before <?php and I removed the ?> tag at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code runs fine on my server (OS X, nginx 1.2.7 with php-fpm 5.4.11). The leading spaces must be coming from a file which is included/loaded before your controller.

To properly return the image as a Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response replace

`imagepng($image);`

with

`ob_start(); 

imagepng($image); 

$imagevariable = ob_get_contents(); 

ob_end_clean(); 

$response->setContent($imagevariable);`

Comment: Actually, I already did that but it didn't change a thing. The generated attachement still as leading spaces. What is weirder is that if I try to save the image in a file with the second argument of imagepng, I can display it normally but when it's in the browser, it's not working.

Comment: That is because you most probably have leading spaces from some previously loaded PHP file. Are you using git? Check if you accidentally change a file like web/app.php or so? If you use imagephp to save the image it just saves the raw image without the spaces. If you want to output it the image data gets returned after the spaces which come from a different file.

Comment: Yes, I'm using git. I'm checking the files to see if there is any leading spaces.

Comment: Any luck? Copy & paste your controller action to a different (Symfony) project to find out if there is something wrong with your php version.

Comment: I solved it thanks to you. I explained where the problem was located in my post in the Edit section.